# Is it possible to express the $n$-th composite as a direct formula involving the $n$-th prime $p(n)$, and/or the prime counting function $\pi(n)$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it possible to express the $n$-th composite integer (or $n$-th odd composite integer) as a direct formula involving the $n$-th prime $p(n)$, and/or the prime counting function $\pi(n)$ ?

Comment: [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A002808) doesn't have one. While that doesn't mean there isn't one, it does lower the chances of one being known.

Comment: arguably, but its down to trying the form $2ab+a+b$ with $2a+1,2b+1$ primes.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram

Comment: You can express the numbers of composite integers below $x$ as $x-\pi(x)-1$ (the "$-1$" is because of $1$ is neither composite nor prime). But there is no direct formula for $\pi(n)$ either.

Comment: There is probably no nice formula of the kind you seek, but there is lots of information at @Arthur 's link http://oeis.org/search?q=4%2C6%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C12%2C14%2C15&language=english&go=Search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $c\left(n\right)$ denote the $n$-th composite integer.

There is exactly $n$ composites and $\pi\left(c\left(n\right)\right)$ primes less than or equal to $c\left(n\right)$, so:

$$c\left(n\right)=n+\pi\left(c\left(n\right)\right)$$

We also know that $n<c\left(n\right)$, therefore:

$$c\left(n\right)\geq n+\pi\left(n\right)$$

If we repeat the same logic, we also know that:

$$c\left(n\right)\geq n+\pi\left(_{n+\pi\left(n\right)}\right)\geq n+\pi\left(n\right)
$$
$$
c\left(n\right)\geq n+\pi\left(_{n+\pi\left(_{n+\pi\left(n\right)}\right)}\right)\geq n+\pi\left(_{n+\pi\left(n\right)}\right)\geq n+\pi\left(n\right)
$$
And so on:
$$
c\left(n\right)=n+\pi_{\left(n+\pi_{\left(n+\pi_{\left(n+\pi_{\left(\ldots\right)}\right)}\right)}\right)}
$$

Although this is a recursive function, the number of iterations needed to find $c\left(n\right)$ is really small. For example, this one works for all $n\leq10^{10}$:
$$
c\left(n\right)=n+\pi\left(n+\pi\left(n+\pi\left(n+\pi\left(n+\pi\left(n+\pi\left(n\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)
$$

Using the same method, we can also find the $n$-th odd composite, which is:

$$
c_{odd}\left(n\right)=2n+2\pi_{\left(2n+2\pi_{\left(2n+2\pi_{\left(2n+2\pi_{\left(\ldots\right)}\right)}\right)}\right)}-1
$$

Example with $c(123456)$:

$$ 123456+\pi\left(123456\right)=135057 $$
$$ 123456+\pi\left(135057\right)=136038 $$
$$ 123456+\pi\left(136038\right)=136124 $$
$$ 123456+\pi\left(136124\right)=136131 $$
$$ 123456+\pi\left(136131\right)=136131 $$
$$ 123456+\pi\left(136131\right)=136131 $$
$$ \ldots $$
$$ c\left(123456\right)=136131 $$

Pseudo-code:

```
function nth_composite(n){
    c = n;
    while(c != n+pi(c)){
        c = n+pi(c);
    } 
    return c;
}
```

Test results:

```
n                   c(n)                Iterations needed

10                  16                  2         
100                 132                 4         
1000                1196                4         
10000               11373               4         
100000              110486              4         
1000000             1084604             5
10000000            10708554            6
100000000           106091744           6
1000000000          1053422338          6
10000000000         10475688326         7
100000000000        104287176418        7
```

Comment: yeah, but you can't tell by $n$ how many recursions you need. also it starts at $n=2$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee  Knowing how many recursions I need is not very important, because I need at least x recursions, not exactly x recursions. The value quickly converge to c(n), so I simply do y=n+pi(y) until I get the same result twice.

Comment: if you do extra recursion unless n=1 you get the wrong answer. I've applied this in code.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee check my edit, I added an example for c(123456)...

Comment: okay well last time I tried it I got c(5)=10 at one point, but c(5)=9 at another.